# Regex: xor of two wilcards?

Tags: regex, grep

I've been trying to make a regex match that will match against CPU instructions like:

```
and val1, val2
sub val1, val2
```

How can I make a regex that can perform a wildcard in place of both of these values BUT, the two values cannot be the same?

```
and ...\, ...
sub ...\, ...
```

But where the first `... !=` the second `...`

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I'm not using any particular programming language, I'm just using the terminal command grep

Comment: @Sasuke added the [tag:grep] tag for ya :)

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497679/117037) might be useful. Otherwise I think grep is too limited to do this properly. I wrote a solution in Python if you're open to it.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't too sure whether grep was capable of doing it. I thought grep might work just to pipe into but python is a good workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
awk -F'[ ,]+' '($1 ~ /^(and|sub)$/) && ($2 != $3)' file
```